# C++ Шаблонный класс TMatrix, реализующий динамический двумерный массив

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, динамические-массивы

есть программа, в которой создан шаблонный класс **TMatrix**, реализующий динамический двумерный массив и функции-методы:

- определения количества элементов массива, которые меньше среднего
  арифметического значения всех элементов четных строк (Метод в коде называется kol_positive);
- нахождения суммы положительных элементов массива (для комплексного числа
  проверяется действительная часть) (Метод в коде называется avrg_real).

Нужно протестировать программу для работы с массивами различных типов: **double** и
класса **комплексное число** (представлено двумя компонентами). Этот класс необходимо
создать.

Сделано практически все, за исключением двух моментов:

1. Как привязать класс "Комплексное число" к шаблонному классу TMatrix;
2. Как реализовать метод, где проверяется действительная часть (avrg_real).

Помогите!

Вот код (заранее извиняюсь за кривизну):

Файл **TMatrix.h**

```
#include<time.h>
 
 
template <class T>
class TMatrix
{
private:
    double kolvo_stolbov, kolvo_strok;
    T** array; // Матрица
public:
 
    double getKolvo_stolbov() const { return kolvo_stolbov; }
    double getKolvo_strok() const { return kolvo_strok; }
 
    // Конструктор по умолчанию
    TMatrix()
    {
        kolvo_stolbov = kolvo_strok = 0;
        array = nullptr;
    }
    
    // Конструктор копий
    TMatrix(const TMatrix& _TM)
    {
        kolvo_stolbov = _TM.kolvo_stolbov;
        kolvo_strok = _TM.kolvo_strok;
 
        array = (T**) new T * [kolvo_strok];
        //array[0] = new T[kolvo_strok * kolvo_stolbov];
 
        for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
            array[i] = (T*) new T[kolvo_stolbov];
            //array[i] = array[0] + i * kolvo_stolbov;
 
        for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
                array[i][j] = _TM.array[i][j];
    }
 
    // Деструктор
    ~TMatrix()
    {
        if (kolvo_stolbov > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
                delete[] array[i];
        }
 
        if (kolvo_strok > 0)
            delete[] array;
    }
 
    // Ввод и вывод данных
    void In();
    void Out();
 
    // Перегрузка операций >> и <<
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const TMatrix& val)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < val.kolvo_strok; i++)
        {
            std::cout << " | ";
            for (int j = 0; j < val.kolvo_stolbov; j++)
                stream << val.array[i][j] << " | ";
            std::cout << endl;
        }
        return stream;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, const TMatrix& val)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < val.kolvo_strok; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < val.kolvo_stolbov; j++)
                stream >> val.array[i][j];
        }
        return stream;
    }
 
    // Метод №1
    double kol_positive(int kolvo_strok, int kolvo_stolbov);
 
    // Метод №2 (Сделан наполовину)
    double avrg_real(int kolvo_strok, int kolvo_stolbov);
 
    void GenerateRandomValues();
    void SetRandomValue();
    void SetValue(int _kolvo_strok, int _kolvo_stolbov, double value);
    void Write();
    void Read();
    TMatrix<T>& operator=(const TMatrix<T>& _TM);
    bool operator==(const TMatrix<T>& _TM);
    bool operator!=(const TMatrix<T>& _TM);
};
 
 
template <class T>
void TMatrix<T>::In()
{
    if (kolvo_stolbov > 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
            delete[] array[i];
 
    if (kolvo_strok > 0)
        delete[] array;
 
    // Количество строк и столбцов матрицы
    std::cin >> kolvo_strok;
    std::cin >> kolvo_stolbov;
    array = (T**) new T * [kolvo_strok];
    //array[0] = new T[kolvo_strok * kolvo_stolbov];
 
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        array[i] = (T*) new T[kolvo_stolbov];
        //array[i] = array[0] + i * kolvo_stolbov;
 
    // Элементы матрицы
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
            std::cin >> array[i][j];
}
 
template <class T>
void TMatrix<T>::Out()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
    {
        std::cout << " | ";
        for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
            std::cout << array[i][j] << " | ";
        std::cout << endl;
    }
}
 
template <class T>
double TMatrix<T>::kol_positive(int kolvo_strok, int kolvo_stolbov)
{
    int avrg;
    int sum = 0;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
    {
        if (i + 1 % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
            {
                sum += array[i][j];
                num1++;
            }
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    avrg = sum / num1;
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
                if (array[i][j] < avrg)
                    num2++;
    
    }
    return num2;
}
 
template <class T>
double TMatrix<T>::avrg_real(int kolvo_strok, int kolvo_stolbov)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
            if (array[i][j] > 0)
                sum += array[i][j];
    }
    return sum;
}
 
template <class T>
void TMatrix<T>::GenerateRandomValues()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    kolvo_stolbov = 1 + rand() % 10;
    kolvo_strok = kolvo_stolbov;
    array = (T**) new T * [kolvo_strok];
    //array[0] = new T[kolvo_strok * kolvo_stolbov];
 
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        array[i] = (T*) new T[kolvo_stolbov];
        //array[i] = array[0] + i * kolvo_stolbov;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
            array[i][j] = (T)(rand() % 101);
}
 
template <class T>
void TMatrix<T>::SetRandomValue()
{
    int _kolvo_strok, _kolvo_stolbov;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cin >> _kolvo_strok >> _kolvo_stolbov;
        srand(time(NULL));
        if ((0 < _kolvo_strok && _kolvo_strok <= kolvo_strok) && (0 < _kolvo_stolbov && _kolvo_stolbov <= kolvo_stolbov))
        {
            array[_kolvo_strok - 1][_kolvo_stolbov - 1] = (T)(rand() % 100);
            break;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "\nERROR!\n\n";
    }
}
 
template <class T>
void TMatrix<T>::SetValue(int _kolvo_strok, int _kolvo_stolbov, double value)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    if ((0 < _kolvo_strok && _kolvo_strok <= kolvo_strok) && (0 < _kolvo_stolbov && _kolvo_stolbov <= kolvo_stolbov))
    {
        array[_kolvo_strok - 1][_kolvo_stolbov - 1] = value;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "\nERROR!\n\n";
}
 
template <class T>
void TMatrix<T>::Write()
{
    ofstream fan;
    fan.open("Matrix_Output.txt", ios::out);
    // Проверка на доступ к файлу
    if (!fan)
    {
        std::cout << "\nThe File Does Not Exist";
        system("pause");
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    if (fan.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        {
            fan << " | ";
            for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
                fan << array[i][j] << " | ";
            fan << endl;
        }
    }
 
    fan.close();
}
 
template <class T>
void TMatrix<T>::Read()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Matrix_Input.txt", ios::in);
    // Проверка на доступ к файлу
    int n, m;
    fin >> kolvo_strok;
    fin >> kolvo_stolbov;
    array = (T**) new T * [kolvo_strok];
    //array[0] = new T[kolvo_strok * kolvo_stolbov];
 
 
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        array[i] = (T*) new T[kolvo_stolbov];
        //array[i] = array[0] + i * kolvo_stolbov;
 
    if (!fin)
    {
        std::cout << "\nThe File Does Not Exist";
        system("pause");
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
                fin >> array[i][j];
        }
    }
    fin.close();
}
 
template <class T>
TMatrix<T>& TMatrix<T>::operator=(const TMatrix<T>& _TM)
{
    if (kolvo_stolbov > 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
            delete[] array[i];
 
    if (kolvo_strok > 0)
        delete[] array;
 
    kolvo_strok = _TM.kolvo_strok;
    kolvo_stolbov = _TM.kolvo_stolbov;
 
    array = (T**) new T * [kolvo_strok];
    //array[0] = new T[kolvo_strok * kolvo_stolbov];
 
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        array[i] = (T*) new T[kolvo_stolbov];
        //array[i] = array[0] + i * kolvo_stolbov;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
            array[i][j] = _TM.array[i][j];
    return *this;
}
 
template <class T>
bool TMatrix<T>::operator==(const TMatrix<T>& _TM)
{
    if (sizeof(array) != sizeof(_TM.array))
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
        if (array[i][j] != _TM.array[i][j])
            return false;
 
    return true;
}
 
template<class T>
bool TMatrix<T>:: operator!= (const TMatrix<T>& _TM) {
    if (sizeof(array) != sizeof(_TM.array))
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_strok; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < kolvo_stolbov; j++)
        if (array[i] == _TM.array[i])
            return true;
 
    return false;
}
```

Файл **TComplex.h**

```
#include <iostream>
 
 
class TComplex
{
    float m_real;
    float m_imaginary;
 
public:
 
    TComplex() : m_real(0), m_imaginary(0) {}
 
    TComplex(float _real, float _imaginary)
        : m_real(_real), m_imaginary(_imaginary) {}
    
    
    float getReal() const { return m_real; }
    float getImaginary() const { return m_imaginary; }
    void setReal(float _real) { m_real = _real; }
    void setImaginary(float _imaginary) { m_imaginary = _imaginary; }
 
    TComplex operator +(const TComplex& _s) const;
 
    std::istream& scan(std::istream& _in = std::cin);
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& _out = std::cout) const;
};
 
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& _in, TComplex& _c);
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& _out, const TComplex& _c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если создаете класс(новый тип), то сначала задумайтесь для чего он нужен, какие свойства должны быть у него и, вообще что это такое и что должны уметь делать экземпляры класса? А затем, используя эти инструменты, решаются конкретные задачи в конкретных функциях. Вы же пытаетесь  раздувать класс методами, решающие конкретные задачи. А если вам зададут еще сотни задач, вы добавите туда еще пару сотен методов?... В добавок вы очень много внимания обращаете на потоковый  ввод и вывод. Если написали оператор ввода(вывода), то  зачем еще и функции для этих целей? Если написали функции и хотите еще иметь и операторы, то последние разумно вывести за пределы класса.

Как конкретно должен выглядеть матричный класс? Ну примерно так: конструкторы, операторы сравнения и присваивания, выполнение некоторых действий с элементами, со строками и столбцами. При желании, добавить транспонирование, операторы сложения, умножения, получения некоторого среза и т.д. и т.п. Не зачем матрице иметь и методы для присваивании своих элементов случайными числами, тем более, что это шаблон класса,  и  элементы шаблонного класса есть числа только при специализации числовыми типами.

Когда вы напишете полезный и годный класс, после и напишете функции(в частности в main), которые  получают специализацию матрицы(например `TMatrix<TComplex>`), может быть еще что то, и решаете там свои задачи. Можно написать и классы, которые специализированы для решения каких либо задач посредством обратного вызова некоторых типов функций, но это уже другая тема и другие обстоятельства и другие решения об их уместности существовать. Как написать полезный(я не говорю хороший, потому что  это частная абстракция, и поэтому нет в стандарте) матричный класс и потом  решить вашу конкретную задачу, по мне, тоже не касается вашему вопросу, но вы пытаетесь делать  не совсем понятные вещи, и, по моему, из за этого не получаете какой либо конкретный ответ.